# How to Apply maximum intensity projection and Minimum intensity projection on DICOM file using python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pydicom

I wanted to Apply maximum intensity projection and Minimum intensity projection on DICOM file using python? i used the following code from GitHub but i am facing issue while i give image to this function

```
def createMIP(np_img, slices_num = 15):
    ''' create the mip image from original image, slice_num is the number of 
    slices for maximum intensity projection'''
    img_shape = np_img.shape
    np_mip = np.zeros(img_shape)
    for i in range(img_shape[0]):
        start = max(0, i-slices_num)
        np_mip[i,:,:] = np.amax(np_img[start:i+1],0)
    return np_mip
```

```
import os
import numpy as np 
from pydicom import dcmread
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_file 
from PIL import Image
directory= "/home/"
f=os.listdir(directory)
size= len([name for name in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, name))])
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".dcm"):
           path=os.path.join(directory,file)
           ds = pydicom.dcmread(path)
           img=ds.pixel_array
            A= createMIP(img)
```

it gives the error of the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-305-fc1fa862cfa8> in <module>
     13            ds = pydicom.dcmread(path)
     14            img=ds.pixel_array
---> 15            A= createMIP(img)

<ipython-input-294-dab2f30d1fa1> in createMIP(np_img, slices_num)
      6     for i in range(img_shape[0]):
      7         start = max(0, i-slices_num)
----> 8         np_mip[i,:,:] = np.amax(np_img[start:i+1],0)
      9     return np_mip

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: You should examine the value of `np_img.shape`, the image loaded might not be 3D. The error message seems to indicate as much.

Comment: That said, it looks like you are applying a max filter, rather than a regular max projection. You could implement this using the dilation operator with a 1D structuring element of length `slices_num`, in the direction along which you want to project.

Comment: np_img.shape gives me (907, 850) values

Comment: Is there is any solution for maximum intensity projection?

Comment: Right, so you have a 2D matrix, you can't index it like it were a 3D one. `np_mip[i,:,:]` is illegal because you index three dimensions, but the matrix has only two dimensions. You can't do a max projection along a 3rd dimension if you don't have a 3rd dimension.

Comment: So how can i processed now?

Comment: That's up to you. I have no idea what you want to accomplish or why. If you don't know what you're trying to do (which this sounds like) you should circle back with your supervisor or whoever gave you this task, and discuss that.

Comment: if i can np_mip[i,:] it works like 2D?